# VueJS: How to have first form select input determine what to show in second select input?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a form with two select inputs. What the user selects in the first select input (`product_id`) is going to determine what options to show in the second select input. Being sort of new to JavaScript, I am struggling with how to write the logic for this in my Vue app.

Let me explain...(also [live demo here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/computed-property-vfor-xm4uq))

I have two data arrays:

> Products:

```
[
  {
    product_id: 1,
    product_name: 'Apple'
  },
  {
    product_id: 2,
    product_name: 'Banana'
  },
  {
    product_id: 3,
    product_name: 'Watermelon'
  },
  {
    product_id: 4,
    product_name: 'Potato'
  }
]
```

> Subjects:

```
[
  {
    product_id: 1,
    subject_name: 'Granny Smith'
  },
  {
    product_id: 1,
    subject_name: 'McIntosh'
  },
  {
    product_id: 2,
    subject_name: 'Cavendish'
  },
  {
    product_id: 3,
    subject_name: 'Jubilee'
  },
  {
    product_id: 3,
    subject_name: 'Black Diamond'
  },
  {
    product_id: 4,
    subject_name: 'Russet'
  },
  {
    product_id: 4,
    subject_name: 'Yukon Gold'
  }
]
```

> Form template:

```
<label for="product_select_input">Product:</label>
          <select
            id="product_select_input"
            v-model="form.product"
          >
            <option disabled value="">Select</option>
            <option
              v-for="(product, index) in products"
              :key="index"
              :value="product.product_id"
              >{{ product.product_name }}</option
            >
          </select>

<label for="product_subject_input">Product Subject:</label>
          <select
            id="product_subject_input"
            v-model="form.subject"
          >
            <option disabled value="">Select a Subject</option>
            <option
              v-for="(subject, index) in subjects"
              :key="index"
              :value="subject.subject_id"
              >{{ subject.subject_name }}</option
            >
          </select>
```

I thought that I would add a computed property called `showRelatedSubjs` and bind it to `@change` on the initial product select, but that did not work and I get the following error in console: `Cannot read property 'product_id' of undefined`

```
computed: {
    showRelatedSubj() {
      if (this.form.product === this.subject.product_id) {
        return this.subjects.filter(subject => subject.includes(this.subject_name))
      } else {
        return ''
      }
    }
  }
```

Anyone have any tips or solutions ? Thank you.

My live [demo is available here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/computed-property-vfor-xm4uq)

Comment: That should be `this.form.subject.product_id` since `v-model` is bound to `form.subject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. The objects in `subjects` contain `product_id`s, yet your `v-model` is bound to `subject.subject_id` (nonexistent).
2. The name of your computed property suggests the intention is to return the related subjects based on the selected product. That should be done with only the `filter()` like this:

```js
showRelatedSubj() {
  return this.subjects.filter(
    subject => this.form.product === subject.product_id
  );
}
```

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/troubleshooting-selects-vmodel-binding-tf0yk?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FPostForm.vue)